# Create and read cookie to confirm logged in user in C# MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, authentication

I have a problem with cookies in MVC3. I want to create a cookie, that stores informations whether the user is logged in. I have never used cookies before and don't know what is the proper way to do it and I am new to MVC3.
Please, can somebody tell me if the approach I used to store cookie is proper or if there is some security risk (the password is encrypted)?
If the cookies are set correctly, how can I use them in other views to check if the user is logged in and set the session for him?
If the approach I use to log in user is wrong, just tell me.

```
public ActionResult Login(string name, string hash, string keepLogged)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hash))
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            byte[] randomData = new byte[sizeof(long)];
            random.NextBytes(randomData);
            string newNonce = BitConverter.ToUInt64(randomData, 0).ToString("X16");
            Session["Nonce"] = newNonce;
            return View(model: newNonce);
        }

        User user = model.Users.Where(x => x.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();
        string nonce = Session["Nonce"] as string;
        if (user == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nonce))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Users");
        }

        string computedHash;
        using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
        {
            byte[] hashInput = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(user.Password + nonce);
            byte[] hashData = sha256.ComputeHash(hashInput);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte value in hashData)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", value);
            }
            computedHash = stringBuilder.ToString();
        }

        if (computedHash.ToLower() == hash.ToLower())
        {                
            Session["IsAdmin"] = user.IsAdmin == 1;
            Session["IDUser"] = user.IDUser;

            ViewBag.IdUser = IDUser;
            ViewBag.IsAdmin = IsAdmin;
            ViewBag.UserName = model.Users.Where(x => x.IDUser == IDUser).First().Name;

            if (keepLogged == "keepLogged")
            {
                //Set user's cookies - is this correct?
                Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("UserCookie", user.IDUser.ToString()));
                Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("PassCookie", user.Password.ToString()));
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Posts");
    }
```

Comment: perhaps you would like to use forms authentication?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This code creates an encrypted cookie with the username

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
    1,
    user.UserName,
    DateTime.Now,
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10),
    false,
    null);

string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

this.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

To enable forms authentication add the following to the `system.web` section of the web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Logon" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Thanks for this example, I will try this, just can you tell me how can I read this cookie in another methods?

Comment: +1, this would be the proper way to handle your authentication.

Comment: You can check if the user is authenticated with this code: if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)

Comment: I have to use your code instead of creating sessions and ViewBags and then in views instead of using ViewBags I will check that IsAuthenticated?
I am sorry for my silly questions, but MVC is really new stuff for me and I don't understand clearly how exactly everything works...

Comment: So I made it work, but when I restart the browser I have to log in again. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Okey, I am just stupid. Didn't realize that I have to set expiration of that new cookie. Sp it works perfectly.
Thank you very much everyone for the help

Answer (score 4):

No,You do not want to store the user's password in a custom cookie.  Look into Forms Authetication.  It does all the cookie work for you.  You can set that forms authetication cookie to persist on the user's computer so that they "stay logged in".

Comment: If I use forms authentication it means I have to change whole login method?

Comment: You could keep the method, but the majority of the code could simply be replaced as per @Vivien Adnot answer

Answer (score 4):

here is my simlified version how you can work with cookies
for remember user name

```
   /// <summary>
   /// Account controller.
   /// </summary>

      public ActionResult LogOn()
      {
         LogOnModel logOnModel = new LogOnModel();

         HttpCookie existingCookie = Request.Cookies["userName"];
         if (existingCookie != null)
         {
            logOnModel.UserName = existingCookie.Value;
         }

         return View(logOnModel);
      }


      public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
      {
         if (model.RememberMe)
         {
            // check if cookie exists and if yes update
            HttpCookie existingCookie = Request.Cookies["userName"];
            if (existingCookie != null)
            {
               // force to expire it
               existingCookie.Value = model.UserName;
               existingCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-20);
            }

            // create a cookie
            HttpCookie newCookie = new HttpCookie("userName", model.UserName);
            newCookie.Expires = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(12);
            Response.Cookies.Add(newCookie);
         }


         // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
         return View(model);
      }
```

Comment: While you have proved that you can save the username in a cookie, you're repeating the wheel. Forms Auth should be used in this scenario.

Comment: @Jesse: this was to demonstrate how to use cookie